# How to deal with many nested if statements for mouse clicking logic?

Tags: c++, conditional-statements

I'm trying to handle mouse clicks in an application, but the logic is becoming very confusing because there are many conditionals. For example, I need to know the following:

-if the control key was held down
-if it was the left or the right mouse button
-if it was the middle or the side of the graphics object that was clicked on
-if the graphics object was already selected or not prior to the click

and most likely more conditionals in the future.

At the moment it's quite confusing trying to write the rules due to the excessive nested conditionals. It's not too bad; I just feel like there must be a better way.

I've read a lot about how to replace nested conditionals with polymorphism, but I can't figure out whether or not that would apply here.

EDIT: I don't know if it matters, but I'm using C++.

Here's an example:

```
if (leftMouseClick)
{
  if (!controlClicked)
  {
    if (!clickedOnRightOfNote)
    {
       if (!isAlreadySelected()) 
       {
         // stuff
       }
       else
       {
         // stuff
       }
    else
    {
       if (!isAlreadySelected())
       {
         // stuff
       }
       else
       {
         // stuff
       }
```

and so forth...

Comment: What language? Please update your question, tagging it with the language and also post an example of your code.

Comment: You probably need to write your logic as a [state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_machine).  It will be much easier to reason about.  In some cases, you can even encode all the logic in a table.

Comment: Have you considered delegating the logic to separate handlers (one per distinct action) instead of one monolithic handler that knows about everything? That would help increase the cohesion. Of course, that assumes each action is independent; if that's not the case, this might not be a good method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split out the actual doing something from the if tree
Write the simplest most readable version first - then think about how to make it better

```
if ( isInShape() ) {
  if ( isCtrl() ) {
    doShapeEdit()
  } else {
    doShapeSelect()
  } 
} else if ( isInBackground() ) {
  if ( isCtrl() ) {
     doSetPreferences();
  } else {
    doSetWahtever();
  }
}
```

Then inside doEditShape() you can handle other special cases

Answer (score 1):

There's a classic UI Pattern where every widget knows it's coordinates. Let's say all widgets derive from an IWidget interface. Then you can have a list of widgets (vector in C++).

When there is a mouse click you can do something like:

```
vector<IWidget*> widgets;
for(int i=0; i<widgets.size(); ++i) {
  if(widgets[i]->contains(x,y)) {
      widgets[i]->handle();
      break;
  } 
}
```

This may not be directly applicable to your exact situation but want to throw it out there as a design idea based on a hierarchy of widgets. It uses polymorphism to avoid if statements.
Really the key principle is that each widget should know about it's coordinates etc.